# SSIS Stuck at Post-Validate when run using a separate AppDomain

Tags: c#, ssis, appdomain

we have a web application that works in conjunction with a local executable that's setup as a Windows service. By design, the web application should course all batch jobs through the service (it can run it of and by itself, again, just not the intended design and something I've no control of). One of those batch job executes SSIS packages. We stumbled upon an issue with the service when it executes the SSIS packages such that it gets stuck after running packages more than twice. At that point we have to restart the service to allow it to run SSIS packages again. We do not encounter this issue if the same job is run while we're debugging the code locally, or running it outside of the service. What we found out as the main difference is that our service runs the job in its own, separate AppDomain. The logic to create that AppDomain is below:

```
private AppDomain CreateAppDomain(string applicationName)
{
    var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var fi = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var info = new AppDomainSetup
    {
        ConfigurationFile = @"D:\Deploy\App\web.config",
        ApplicationBase = @"D:\Deploy\App",
        ApplicationName = applicationName,
        CachePath = fi.Directory.Parent.FullName + @"\Temp",
        ShadowCopyDirectories = @"D:\Deploy\App\bin",
        PrivateBinPath = "bin",
        ShadowCopyFiles = "true"
    };

    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(uid.ToString(), null, info);
    return domain;
}
```

That trickles down to the following lines of code:

```
var domain = CreateAppDomain("DomainOfInstance1");

                // Use thread info from the calling process
                if (threadPrincipal != null)
                {
                    domain.SetThreadPrincipal(threadPrincipal);
                }
                
                var tt = (LocalWindowsService)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(LocalWindowsService).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Default, null, null, null, null);
                tt.OnThreadDone += LocalWindowsService_OnThreadDone;
                id = tt.StartJob(id, parameters);

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("started job: {0}", id));
```

And the corresponding code to execute the package is:

```
        var ssisRunEventHandler = new SsisRunEventHandler(sqlObject, process);
        Package.Execute(null, null, ssisRunEventHandler, null, null);
```

If I call the job using my local machine while debugging or through the Application Pool of my Web App that's hosted in C:\Windows.NET.. instead of D:\Deploy\App, I can keep running SSIS for as many times as I like. When that same code of Package.Execute is run through the AppDomain, however, SSIS freezes on post-validate after calling execute against any SSIS package twice.

What we found out as a workaround is to explicitly call AppDomain.Unload(domain) to prevent it from freezing up, but feels to me like a hack - and that we're getting exceptions about domain unload and thread abort exceptions as a consequence. I was hoping to try and get to the bottom of it more, but is just way outside of my domain to know if there are even tools out there that can help me understand what's getting stuck within integration services when the package is run on a separate domain. Nothing in Event Viewer and/or our own logs tell anything odd either (I have the package logging enabled).

Has anyone encountered the same issue and have recommendations as to which tools, if any, can I use to troubleshoot some more?

Not sure if it helps, but some additional details:
SQL Server DB is 2016
Integration Services at v13.0.0.0
Using SQLNCLI11 for the provider in our connection string to the destination
Delimited files as our sources